# How do I correctly compare values across tables with triggers? (PL-SQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am currently not able to get a trigger working in Oracle SQL. I am trying to compare values across tables. More specifically, I want to see if a date is bigger / later than another date, depending on the result, an error can occur, i.e. project budget entry date can't be before the start date of the project.

I have two tables that are relevant.

Project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqJuD.png

Budget: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5561.png

This is my trigger:

```
-- check legality of budget date
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_budget_date 
BEFORE UPDATE OF budget_date ON budget 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE var_project_start DATE;
BEGIN

    SELECT project.project_start
    INTO var_project_start
    FROM project
    WHERE project.project_id = :new.project_id;

    IF :new.budget_date > var_project_start THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Budget made before project start.');
    END IF;

END;
/
```

To showcase how my trigger doesn't work, I'll first explain how I test it.

```
SELECT project_id, project_start
FROM project
WHERE project_id = '8';
```

The result is 15-SEP-18. Now let's try to insert a budget before the start date, let's say 13-SEP-18.

```
INSERT INTO budget VALUES (8, 9000, '13-SEP-18', 4);
```

After running those two commands, this the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJAl6.png

As you can see, it doesn't appear to work at all. The budget for the project (8) gets added as if the trigger didn't work at all.

If anyone can see a problem, point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you so much for the read and your time.

Comment: You have created an update trigger, and doing an insert which is not what you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I miss something, but to me it seems simple. Your trigger runs only before update, you should add BEFORE INSERT as well. Check the following pattern:

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] TRIGGER trigger_name  
BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE or DELETE
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yup, you helped me sort it out. Thank you Roland.